# Redirect to same server on different port and path

Tags: javascript

need your help in this please :)

I have a page : http://x.x.x.x:4444/pages/hello.html

if visited , then redirected to the following page

http://x.x.x.x:5555/cgi-bin/hello.cgi?mode=welcome

Thanks !

Comment: Just do a redirection ... Where is the problem ? What is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in 'hello.html':

```
<script>
top.location = "//x.x.x.x:5555/cgi-bin/hello.cgi?mode=welcome";
</script>
```